# Android Views pushed off of LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a vertical `LinearLayout` with a `TextView`, a custom view (replaced with `VideoView` to illustrate the problem), and a `Button`. I want the `TextView` horizontally centered on the top, and the `Button` horizontally centered on the bottom (as well as vertically centered in the remaining space between `VideoView` and bottom of the screen). The `VideoView` should occupy at most the space between the `TextView` and the `Button`. However, in my implementation the `VideoView` pushes the `TextView` and the `Button` off of the screen, despite the height being set to `wrap_content`. Everything works if I set the `VideoView` height to a manual height. What am I doing wrong? I tried playing around with layout weights but couldn't get anything working.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="title"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Space
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="button" />

    <Space
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: pushed off screen]

Comment: @MikeM. this works as I'd expect if I remove the `layout_weight` attributes from the `Space` components which I use to vertically center the `Button` in the remaining space. Is there any way I can allow the `VideoView` to consume as much space as it needs while still allowing my `Button` to be vertically centered in the remaining space?

Comment: Oh, sorry, never mind that. I misunderstood what you were going for. Might be easier to use something like `ConstraintLayout` instead.

Comment: Does it also looks broken on your phone or only in the preview? I think you also should add a `ScrollView` because with `wrap_content` you cannot know how big your `VideoView` will be and it could always push your Button out. If you want to fit everything on one screen I also would suggest `ConstraintLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Jeff,

I believe it's easier to use constraint layout instead here.
The current problem is that you can't determine the size of videoview because it has a wrap_content height

which is trying to take over the whole space in this case

In Constraint layout if you are trying to achieve the following:
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="title"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/titleTextView" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

if you are interested on how it should be fixed in LinearLayout
I believe you will need to remove all <Space
and add the weight to the VideoView